# Symfony form global error linked to a field that has no error

Tags: php, forms, symfony

Form before handleRequest: no global errors.

```
Form {#1852 ▼
  -config: FormBuilder {#1851 ▶}
  -parent: null
  -children: OrderedHashMap {#1836 ▶}
  -errors: []
  -submitted: false
  -clickedButton: null
  -modelData: User {#2096 ▶}
  -normData: User {#2096 ▶}
  -viewData: User {#2096 ▶}
  -extraData: []
  -synchronized: true
  -defaultDataSet: true
  -lockSetData: false
}
```

Request: 'firstname' field is passed.

```
Request {#3 ▼
  +attributes: ParameterBag {#6 ▶}
  +request: ParameterBag {#4 ▼
    #parameters: array:1 [▼
      "registration" => array:6 [▼
        "firstname" => "foo"
        "lastname" => "bar"
        "email" => "foo@test.com"
        "accountType" => "bbbbbb"
        "school_info" => array:4 [▶]
        "_token" => "1a55e2d7474183267374a0007e15b92e6114158d"
      ]
   ]
  }
...
}
```

Form after handleRequest: global error with error message from 'firstname' field, but no error in the field itself.

```
Form {#1852 ▼
-config: FormBuilder {#1851 ▶}
  -parent: null
  -children: OrderedHashMap {#1836 ▼
    -elements: array:5 [▼
      "firstname" => Form {#1835 ▼
        -config: FormBuilder {#1854 ▶}
        -parent: Form {#1852}
        -children: OrderedHashMap {#1853 ▶}
        -errors: []
        -submitted: true
        -clickedButton: null
        -modelData: "poipoi"
        -normData: "poipoi"
        -viewData: "poipoi"
        -extraData: []
        -synchronized: true
        -defaultDataSet: true
        -lockSetData: false
      }
      "email" => Form {#1858 ▶}
      "lastname" => Form {#1861 ▶}
      "accountType" => Form {#1864 ▶}
      "school_info" => Form {#1867 ▶}
    ]
    -orderedKeys: array:5 [▶]
    -managedCursors: []
  }
  -errors: array:3 [▼
    0 => FormError {#728 ▼
      -message: "missing email"
      #messageTemplate: "missing email"
      #messageParameters: array:1 [▶]
      #messagePluralization: null
    }
    1 => FormError {#733 ▼
      -message: "missing firstname"
      #messageTemplate: "missing firstname"
      #messageParameters: array:1 [▶]
      #messagePluralization: null
    }
    2 => FormError {#738 ▼
      -message: "missing lastname"
      #messageTemplate: "missing lastname"
      #messageParameters: array:1 [▶]
      #messagePluralization: null
    }
  ]
  -submitted: true
  -clickedButton: null
  -modelData: User {#2096 ▶}
  -normData: User {#2096 ▶}
  -viewData: User {#2096 ▶}
  -extraData: []
  -synchronized: true
  -defaultDataSet: true
  -lockSetData: false
}
```

Same issue for 'firstname', 'lastname' and 'email'. Notice how the errors are global to the form, and there is no error in the fields themselves. Also, error bubbling does not affect the issue.

Form Type:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\SiteBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Acme\SiteBundle\Entity\User;

/**
 *
 */
class RegistrationType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('firstname', null, array('label' => 'firstname'))
            ->add('lastname', null, array('label' => 'lastname'))
            ->add('email', 'email', array('label' => 'form.email'))
            ->add('accountType', 'choice'));

        $builder->add('school_info', 'school_info', array(
                'label' => 'School',
                'cascade_validation' => false,
                'mapped' => false,
                'required' => false,
        ));        
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\\SiteBundle\\Entity\\User',
            'intention' => 'registration',
            'validation_groups' => function (FormInterface $form) {
                $data = $form->getData();
                if ($this->isPro($data)) {
                    return array('HKCustomRegistration', 'account_type_pro');
                } else {
                    return array('HKCustomRegistration', 'account_type');
                }
            },
            'cascade_validation' => true,
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'registration';
    }

}
```

Embedded Form (school_info) Form Type.

**Key point** : The issue only happens when the school_info form is added as a field in the registration form and shool input is filled in (if not filled in, bug does not happen).

```
<?php

namespace Acme\SiteBundle\Form\Type;

use Acme\SiteBundle\Service\SiteProvider;
use Acme\SiteBundle\Entity\School;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class SchoolInfoType extends AbstractType
{
    private $site;

    public function __construct(SiteProvider $siteProvider)
    {
        $this->site = $siteProvider->getCurrentSiteDB();

    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $site = $this->site;
        $builder
            ->add('school', 'entity', array(
                'empty_value' => '------------',
                'class' => 'AcmeSiteBundle:School',
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($site) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('sc')
                              ->where('sc.site = :site')
                              ->setParameter('site', $site)
                              ->addOrderBy('sc.name', 'ASC');
                },
                'mapped' => true, // mapped but not persisted
                'label' => 'school',
            ));

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\SiteBundle\Entity\User',
            'site' => null,
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'school_info';
    }
```

Validation constraints in the Entity:

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="firstname", type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
 * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"HKCustomRegistration", "HKCustomProfile", "Default", "sylius"}, message="missing firstname")
 */
private $firstname;
```

Comment: Codes of your Form Type, Form Builder would be helpful for start.

Comment: I've added the form types.

Comment: Not sure how much relevant the school_info form type is, but I think the registration type itself is quite standalone. Have you tried to render only the registration type form and see if the problem exists on that case?

Comment: The issue only happens when the school_info form is added as a field in the registration form. Furthermore, it only happens when at some point before submitting the regsitration form, an ajax call to populate the school_info form has been made. Let me add the ajax call.

Comment: The code itself does not show any problem to me yet, but validation constraints can also be placed in Entities as well. The thing to try would be to pinpoint which form/subform is causing that. Now that we know that the problem happens with school_info is added, add and remove its subform to narrow down the problem.

Comment: I can remove fields in school_info and test that. Will do that. What seems strange to me is that the error message is a custom error message added to the 'firstname' field only (same for 'lastname' and 'email'). I'll add the Entity with the relevant validation constraints.

Comment: Making progress ! The bug has nothing to do with the ajax call. It happens if school_type is reduced to a single field. I've updated the info above. Testing more...

Comment: Thanks for the help !

Comment: Good for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so it was a validation group error !

The `schoolInfoType` validated the `User` entity against the default validation group, which requires `'firstname'`, `'lastname'` and `'email'`.
It was a bit misleading because those fields were filled in the parent form.
(not sure if `'mapped' => false` plays a role here).

Anyway, my solution was to add a validation group with no associated constraints to `SchoolInfoType`:

```
<?php
class SchoolInfoType extends AbstractType
{
    //...
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\SiteBundle\Entity\User',
            'validation_groups' => array('school'),
            'site' => null,
        ));
    }
}
?>
```